# How to get list of row that has value from a range of data based on column header as the criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, google-sheets-formula, reporting

I have a range of data populated from a google form in sheet "Data".
I need to make a report (in sheet "Report") that shows the students attendance, based on name (from drop down list). The data that is blank is excluded in that report, as seen in column i to column k

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYacs.png)

I have shared the [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZL9AKYixFE5G6_8TUaVrwIecImG2nSJ7eSK7UY-jlQU/edit#gid=464284604)

I have tried to use filter
=filter(Data!B1:I20,Data!E1:E20<>"")

but still I cant find the way to change the "condition" in this formula to refer to the sheet Report A1.

what is the correct formula to achieve this?

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: The file you shared is locked, if you want us to help you please remove every type of authorization from it. Anyway I think that with a **pivot table** you can achieve what you're trying to do

Comment: ooh so sorry i forgot to open the share..
It's opened now..

thank you

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want like a sum of every subject of each day where the student was present? (And so the field in the Data sheet blank)?

Comment: The desired report is shown in column i to column k in the sheet Report..

Comment: I have tried to use filter =filter(Data!B1:I20,Data!E1:E20<>"")

but the "condition" in this function must be taken from the dropdownlist A1 sheet report.
and also, the result should only show the record of that students.

Comment: Have you thought of using Apps Script? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: Hi @Kessy .. 
Im totally blind about Appscript :)
but let me try.. 

any advice about which appscript that might handle my need?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Apps Script you will have to use the function [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).

Example:

```
// The code below logs the index of a sheet named "Expenses"
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Expenses");
if (sheet != null) {
  Logger.log(sheet.getIndex());
}
```

Then to find from column E the rows that have value you would have to use the [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) method:

```
// Get a range A1:D4 on sheet titled "Invoices"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getRange("Invoices!A1:D4");

// Get cell A1 on the first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
```

Then you would have to iterate over that rows and get the rows where the E column has something.

Once you have that you can get the `Report` sheet and set the values there with [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

For more information on how the function you may need to use you have the reference of [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) and the overview on [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)